# Leading '/' while reading a file in Android

Tags: android, filenames, filepath, fileinputstream, slash

My file's actual location in SDcard is :

```
mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg
```

If I use the same for reading , for example :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg");
```

The above case works fine :)

But, If I use them like :

```
String s="mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg";

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(s);
```

The above case does not work, as it puts a leading '/'. and the file path becomes

```
/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg
```

And therefore a `java.io.FileNotFoundException is thrown`

Please help me out in fixing this small issue.Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have an extra space in `String s` at the end. The leading slash is not the problem.

Comment: Yeah, remove the space at the end. That should solve the issue.

Comment: I have removed the extra space from the String path as you said it was just a typo. You can rollback the edit anytime, if it is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry for this silly typo error here, I am taking care of spaces in actual code.

Comment: I want to encrypt a file, from my sdcard, so in that case,I want to read the file first.As the system could not find the file at appropriate path (due to leading '/'), it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException. I have also used substring(1) on the actual string but eventually it evaluates to /nt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg [m removed from mnt, but '/' remains]

Comment: Use **String s="sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mnt+s);** and see its work or not?

Comment: where mnt values to ?

Comment: @Happy_New_Year_Everyone:Something like **FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mnt" + s);**?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, but unfortunately they could not fix up the issue. It looks v.simple, I wonder why is it behaving so rude :P

Answer (score 1):

You have given a space after Image path. Change your code from

```
String s="mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg ";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(s);
```

to

```
String s="mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(s);
```

Comment: he removed the space after `.jpg`, which is most likely the reason you get FNF exception

Comment: I am sorry for this silly typo error here, I am taking care of spaces in actual code.

Comment: I want to encrypt a file, from my sdcard, so in that case,I want to read the file first.As the system could not find the file at appropriate path (due to leading '/'), it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException. I have also used substring(1) on the actual string but eventually it evaluates to /nt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/IMG_20140127_123605.jpg [m removed from mnt, but '/' remains]